# Yellowish, brown and burning of leaves of greenhouse cucumber,according to fallen flowers without producing fruit

Tags: fruits, cucumbers

My cucumber plants,was growing well,and 4 weeks ago have started to flowering while their leaves beginning to **yellow**,brown and **burning**.
Then the **flowers are falling** and the **fruits become small** and do not grow, and after a few days **fade and dying**.
so that I earn 15 kg cucumbers from land with an area of 500 Square meters for every day.
I checked climate change, but this problem did not depend on water or heat...the used **Variety** is **profusion**؛ Kareem F1 Hybrid, and the season for our location is autumn, and the they are short,so that the total time of Radiation is 8 hours. I confused the problem was happen by the shortening of days or these marks are Symptoms of Nutrient Deficiencies on Cucumbers? and what kinds of deficiencies?
There are some pictures.
Thanks for your attention...
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are they growing under cover, like in a heated greenhouse or polytunnel, or outdoors? Where are you in the world?

Comment: I should have said, is the greenhouse heated at night and has it been colder there recently overnight?

Comment: Do they have enough magnesium?